# For loop Join with &

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var substr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (var i = 0; i < substr.length; i++) {
    var urls = 'url' + substr[i];
    var joinArr = urls.join('&');
    console.log("JoinArray", joinArr);
}
```

Will join work to get output like this?

> url1=&url2=&url3=&url4=&url5=&url6=

Comment: `join` is an array operation. `urls` is a string, not an array.

Comment: One thing you can do is anytime your question is "Will this work?" is to actually run the code and see what it gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a valid query string, but you could use `map` instead:

```
var joinArr = substr.map(n => "url" + n).join("=&") + "=";
```

Answer (score 2):

`join` is a method on arrays, but `urls` is a string, not an array.

You should push the string onto an array, and call `join` at the end.

And if you want them to have `=`, you need to concatenate that as well.

```js
var substr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var urls = [];
for (var i = 0; i < substr.length; i++) {
  urls.push('url' + substr[i] + '=');
}
var joinArr = urls.join('&');
console.log("JoinArray", joinArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the index values and replace the numbers by the specific pattern.

```js
var substr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var str = substr.join('').replace(/[0-9]/g, (n) => `url${n}=&`).slice(0, -1);
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since question is tagged jQuery, you can use [`$.param()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) on a reduced object

```js
var substr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

var query = $.param(substr.reduce((a,c)=> (a['url' + c]='',a),{}))

console.log(query)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about...

```
var substr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
console.log('url'+substr.join('=&url')+'=');

//output:   url1=&url2=&url3=&url4=&url5=&url6=
```

?